# How to get the matching token parameter value in an action method?

Tags: grammar, raku

If I have something like this in my grammar:

```
grammar G {
    token tab-indent(Int $level) {
        # Using just ** $level would require <!before \t> to have the same effect, so use a code block for simplicity.
        \t+ <?{ $/.chars == $level }>
    }
}
```

is there some way to directly get the value of `$level` in the corresponding action `method tab-indent($/)`?

Right now I redo `$/.chars` there too, which works, but doesn't seem ideal, especially in more complex situations, where the value of the parameter can be less easy to deduce from the matching text.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `\t ** {$level}`

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry for the misleading comment. `** {$level}` does work, it just doesn't do quite the same thing. I've updated the comment to be more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a dynamic variable to pass information to the methods of an action class.

```raku
grammar G {
  token TOP {
    <tab-indent(2)> $<rest> = .*
  }

  token tab-indent(Int $level) {
    :my $*level = $level; # has to be in this scope, not in a block
    \t ** {$level}
  }
}

class A {
  method tab-indent($/) {
    say '$*level = ', $*level;
  }
}

say G.parse( actions => A.new, "\t\t\t" );
```

```
$*level = 2
｢           ｣
 tab-indent => ｢        ｣
 rest => ｢  ｣
```

Comment: This is much nicer, thanks!

Comment: very neat! a while back I struggled with passing objects around action methods due to the "random" sequence of action method calls -- so I guess that's also a use for dynamic variables...

Comment: You can simplify to `token tab-indent(Int $*level) { \t ** {$*level}  }`.